# how to find out all the applications that can open the same content type in iPad?

Tags: ipad

how to find out all the applications that can open the same content type in iPad? Is there any API to find out this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIDocumentInteractionController` as the following:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfName" ofType:@"pdf"]];

_docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url] retain];

BOOL isValid = [_docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(980, 52, 0, 0) inView:self animated:YES];
```

It will open a menu with all the options to read that file. You can also use its `delegate` `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` to have more control of it.